# Cannot starting android emulator

Tags: android-emulator

I am studying about phonegap. I run Android Virtual Device Manager, selected a device and click started. After `starting android emulator` finished loading.

I saw `emulator-arm.exe` in the task manager and it took some memory resource. But no emulator appeared. After about 10 seconds, emulator-arm.exe disappeared from task manager.

I couldn't start Android Emulator. Please help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you use the latest version of the platform-tools and the image? Run "android" script in your android-sdk/tools folder, and update all items related with emulators. Then, run "AVD Manager" in the root folder of the SDK. Then, create a virtual machine based on a real device of your choice. Then, run and wait, emulator takes some time to appear.

Other better choice would be use [Genymotion emulator](http://www.genymotion.com), which has more speed and stability. Good luck!

Comment: Any news here? Did this question help you?